# How to extract parts of a URL column

Tags: 2013, jslink, edit-form

I've got a jslink client-side rendering file for an edit form. It has a url column for which the basic structure of the item data is returned like:

```
"https://<link path>,<friendly display for link>"
```

And our code splits it on the comma to then manipulate and display the information. That was working until somebody uploaded a file with commas in its name. Those are encoded like this:

```
"https://<path>/This,, that,, and the other.xlsx, This, that, and the other.xlsx"
```

I'm trying to figure out how to break the information into the two parts. Does anybody know how SP does this internally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that internally SP 2013 uses `SPClientTemplates.Utility.ParseURLValue()` to return an object of the form `{URL:<value>,Description:<value>}` from the value of a URL column while rendering an edit or display form. (I assume a list view too, but I didn't check that.)

I went poking in the `_layouts/15/clienttemplates.debug.js` and this is how they do it.

```
    var urlValue = {
        'URL': 'http://',
        'Description': ''
    };

    if (valueStr == null || valueStr == '')
        return urlValue;
    var idx = 0;

    while (idx < valueStr.length) {
        if (valueStr[idx] == ',') {
            if (idx == valueStr.length - 1) {
                valueStr = valueStr.substr(0, valueStr.length - 1);
                break;
            }
            else if (idx + 1 < valueStr.length && valueStr[idx + 1] == ' ') {
                break;
            }
            else {
                idx++;
            }
        }
        idx++;
    }
    if (idx < valueStr.length) {
        urlValue.URL = (valueStr.substr(0, idx)).replace(/\,\,/g, ',');
        var remainderLen = valueStr.length - (idx + 2);

        if (remainderLen > 0)
            urlValue.Description = valueStr.substr(idx + 2, remainderLen);
    }
    else {
        urlValue.URL = valueStr.replace(/\,\,/g, ',');
        urlValue.Description = valueStr.replace(/\,\,/g, ',');
    }
    return urlValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just try to split on the comma first, and if you end up with more than two parts then `indexOf('.xlsx,') + 5` would give you the index of the comma you're trying to split on, and you could `slice` using that info.  Or [`string.match(regex)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) if you need to handle other file types and need to check for other extensions.  You can get index information from the match.

Comment: That sounds complex and like it might have a lot of edge cases that are tricky to account for -- especially since it could be any value that a URL column allows, not just files. I found the answer which I'll post.